# Can't call javascript function in another javascript file

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js

I'm probably doing something wrong i just can't figure out what it is.
Here in "File1.js" i make a function called `weeklyfunc()`

```js
function weeklyfunc() {
  var chain = _.cloneDeep(_.chain(state.items).filter({
    'id': 1
  }).head().value());

  chain.startDate = "2020-03-17";
  chain.endDate = "2020-03-17";
  chain.id = 2343;
  chain.index = 8;
  chain.leftDistanceInitPX = 408;
  chain.leftDistancePX = 408;

  modifiedItems.push(chain);
}
```

And here in "File2.js" I try to call the function.

```
check: function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.value === "custom")
    document.getElementById("expandrepeat").style.display = 'block';
  else if (ev.target.value === "weekly")
    weeklyfunc();
  else
    document.getElementById("expandrepeat").style.display = 'none';
},
```

This does not work how can i fix this?

Comment: File1.js is loaded before File2.js ?

Comment: Please define "_This does not work_". How are the files loaded? Are they loaded? Have you checked the Network tab in the DevTools? Are you getting an error message? How is`check` called?

Comment: @Teemu I'm getting the error message: "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function". Check is called at @change="check" in a <select>

Comment: That's weird ... `Object` is an intrinsic function in JS. Maybe the error is not in the posted code at all. Can you provide a [minimal and  reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Teemu i can't really recreate the problem but this is what it looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/2zf6k9st/7/

Answer (score 0):

Try export

```
export yourfunction() {
    //...
}
```

And then importing your it wherever you want to use it

Comment: weeklyfunc() is in a getter and the getter is exported and i imported weeklyfunc in the other file. Still not working with error: "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function"

Comment: You need to export weeklyfunc anyway